# Using smooth in ggplot2 to fit a linear model using the errors given in the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data frame:

```
> dat
   x         y        yerr
1 -1 -1.132711 0.001744498
2 -2 -2.119657 0.003889120
3 -3 -3.147378 0.007521881
4 -4 -4.220129 0.012921450
5 -5 -4.586586 0.021335644
6 -6 -5.389198 0.032892630
7 -7 -6.002848 0.048230946
```

And I can plot it with the standard error smoothing as:

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
p <- p + geom_errorbar(data=dat, aes(x=x, ymin=y-yerr, ymax=y+yerr), width=0.09)
p + geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x)
```

[image]

But what I need is to use the **yerr** to fit my linear model. Is it possible with ggplot2?

Comment: How do you want to use it? I'm sure its possible... but I have no idea  what you're expecting!

Comment: @Justin Hi. I need the graph similar to this but with the "correct" (let's say) fit to put in a publication (using the yerr from dat), and if I could get the parameters of the linear model (the A and B from: y = A + B*x) directly from ggplot it would be nice, but that part I know how to do by hand so it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: @Justin yerr is the error of the y value.

Comment: I don't think anyone understands what you mean by "use the yerr to fit my linear model". Can you explicitly describe the model you're thinking of?

Comment: @joran Any fit in real science must take the measurement errors (yerr according to the original question) into account, you cannot just use the points like they all have the same measurement error and fit a curve trough them. I did some fiddling around and posted the answer below.

Comment: @jbssm There's no need to be defensive, but there are many scientific disciplines _other_ than physics, in which things are done differently. Doing experiments with physical instruments with none error rates is something you do regularly, but it's something that, say, a wildlife biologist would find pretty foreign. To them, the idea that you have _known_ measurement errors on your y variables would be pretty weird.

Comment: ...also, I'd point out that once you say "do a regression that incorporates known instrument error on the y variable" I understand what you mean exactly. But that kind of linear model isn't what I'd call _common_ (and I have a PhD in statistics!).

Comment: @joran But hat is the difference if I say that the error comes from the instrument error of from any other source where we managed to calculate it? Sincerely, it's completely clear by the code - if not by the graph - that the error is known, it's part of the present data of the example, and the question on how to fit it couldn't be more direct than this.

Comment: @jbbsm It isn't clear at all what *exactly* `yerr` is. Given you wanted a weighted least squares fit I presume this is a standard error on the observed `y` but you keep talking about it as "error", which I would normally take to be the difference between the real value and the measured one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I found a way to answer this.

Since in any scientific experiment where we gather data, if that experiment is correctly executed, all the data values must have an error associated.

**In some cases the variance of the error may be equal in all the points, but in many, like the present case states in the original question, that is not true.** So we must use that different in the variances of the error values for different measurements when fitting a curve to our data.

That way to do it is to attribute the weight to the error values, which according to statistical analysis methods are equal to 1/sqrt(errorValue), so, it becomes:

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, weight = 1/sqrt(yerr))) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-yerr, ymax=y+yerr), width=0.09) + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x)
```

[image]

Comment: @GavinSimpson 1st - **If you look at the graphs you actually see that the fit is different**. 2nd - Try and actually run the given code and if that's not too much to ask before you give a down-vote without knowing what are you talking about, change the value of the yerr and see that **yes** it takes the given weights into account. 3rd - If you know what are you talking about, at least give an alternative instead of just bashing based on an example you didn't event tested.

Comment: I'm sorry that this question has been such a negative experience. Several people misunderstood your answer, but on the other hand, note that Gavin realized his mistake and specifically edited your question so that he (and others) could remove their down votes.

Comment: As for the down votes on the question, I think some people are reacting to our discussion regarding my request for some clarification about the type of model you're fitting. Some people probably thought that your response was a little defensive (and maybe a bit rude) when all we wanted was a little more explanation so that we could help you better.

Comment: I take back my criticism; it seems a hack in `stat_smooth()` allows the `weight` aesthetic to be passed on to the `weights` argument of `lm()`, which is doing what you wanted (which I never had a problem with,, though your terminology was confusing - hence the edit I made to your Q as it is the *variances* that are allowed to vary in a weighted least squares fit). The edit has allowed me to remove my -1 and turn it to a +1. Please accept my apologies for jumping the gun earlier.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thank you Gavin. I've been away the past days and only saw your edits now.

Answer (score 6):

For any model fitting, I would do the fitting outside of the plotting paradigm I was using. For this, pass a value to `weights` that is inversely proportional to the variances of the observations. Fitting will then be done via a weighted least squares procedure.

For your example/situation **ggplot**'s `geom_smooth` is doing the following for you. Whist it may seem easier to use `geom_Smooth`, the benefits of fitting the model directly eventually outweigh this. For one, you have the fitted model and can perform diagnostics on the fit, assumptions of the model etc.

Fit the weighted least squares

```
mod <- lm(y ~ x, data = dat, weights = 1/sqrt(yerr))
```

Then `predict()` from the model over the range of `x`

```
newx <- with(dat, data.frame(x = seq(min(x), max(x), length = 50)))
pred <- predict(mod, newx, interval = "confidence", level = 0.95)
```

In the above we get the `predict.lm` method to generate the appropriate confidence interval for use.

Next, prepare the data for plotting

```
pdat <- with(data.frame(pred),
             data.frame(x = newx, y = fit, ymax = upr, ymin = lwr))
```

Next, build the plot

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
       geom_point() +
       geom_line(data = pdat, colour = "blue") + 
       geom_ribbon(mapping = aes(ymax = ymax, ymin = ymin), data = pdat, 
                   alpha = 0.4, fill = "grey60")
p
```

Comment: This *is* what I would have said if I didn't have my head up my ass earlier.

Comment: Thank you. This is a bit what I was doing by hand. I actually had the fit values, but didn't knew how to make ggplot puting them over the graph with the confidence intervals, so I though to use the automates fit done by ggplot.

Comment: Note one can also draw the line with `geom_abline()` and the slope and intercept taken from the fit coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague. Here's a couple of suggestions that may get you started.

1. ggplot2 is just using the `lm` function for regression. To get the values, just do:

   ```
    lm(y ~ x, data=dat)
   ```

   this will give you the y-intercept and gradient.
2. You can switch off the standard error in the `stat_smooth` using the `se` argument:

   ```
   .... + geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE)
   ```
3. You can add a ribbon through your points/error bands with:

   ```
   ##This doesn't look good. 
   .... + geom_ribbon(aes(x=x, ymax =y+yerr, ymin=y-yerr))
   ```

Comment: Thank you for taking some time to answer, but I sincerely don't see how the question is vague. Anytime you make a scientific experiment, this is the way you must fit your data, taking the errors into account, which in the real world are seldom equal in all the gathered data point.
I found an answer and have put it below.

Comment: @jbssm Look at @joran's comment above (which everyone agreed with). Also the *best* way to take account of your error is to use the raw data, not to summarise using `yerr`. The model you have now fitted assumes non-constant variance. So instead of epsilon_i ~ N(0, sigma^2) it is now epsilon_i ~ N(0, sigma^2 w_i).

Comment: What raw data? I'm measuring something and I know that for some value x[1] I got the value y[1] and my instrument error is yerr[1], and for so forth... like it happens in basically every physics paper, sorry if that's so strange for so many people.

Comment: @jbssm 1. You didn't explain your problem. In your question, where is the phrase "instrument error". 2. Why would anyone on a computer Q & A website have any idea what happens in "basically every physics paper". 3. Your problem isn't strange. It's just badly explained.

Comment: No, that's because in the R part of this forum no one bothers to actually look at the code presented, they just read the last question of a post and discard it. If someone couldn't understand what yerr is (which by it's own name is pretty self explanatory), would easily understand when seeing it was used to give the error intervals for the graph presented in all 3 lines of code that they actually had to read to see all the post.