# Propagate the envelope of measurement uncertainty around each point through a linear model in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, uncertainty

I have fit the following linear model, which I have graphed using the ggplot2 code and data snippet below. I used a monte carlo approach to quantify uncertainties associated with each var2 data point (standard deviation of noisy point estimates from 10000 monte carlo simulations) stored in var6 (same units as var 2). However, I am unsure how to incorporate those uncertainties into the plot.

I have scoured the web/stackexchange, and found a number of similar queries but no concrete answers, such as [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235693/linear-model-where-the-data-has-uncertainty-using-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636052/using-smooth-in-ggplot2-to-fit-a-linear-model-using-the-errors-given-in-the-data). The only tangible solution that I have uncovered from my search is the possibility of weighting the points in proportion to their uncertainties in the `lm` function (the inverse of the square root of my uncertainties), but I really don't think that's what I'm after.

Instead, I would like to be able to feed the range of values (var2 +/- var6) into my model to generate an envelope of predicted values, which accounts for the uncertainties in var6.

Please advise, thank you!

[image]

ggplot2 code:

```
ggplot(data = dat, 
       aes(x = var1, y = var2, color = as.factor(var3))) +
  stat_smooth(size = 2, method = lm, formula = y ~log(x), 
              show.legend = F, fullrange = F, se = F) +
  geom_point(size = 3)+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 14), 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14), 
        strip.text = element_text(size = 14), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 14), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 14)) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Data

```
> structure(list(var1 = c(5L, 5L, NA, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
NA, 2L, 15L, 18L, 8L, 3L, NA, 2L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 13L, 2L, 
7L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 20L, 3L, 14L, 
12L, 1L, NA, 2L), var2 = c(12809.4897078949, 20942.2363261915, 
32579.6236531272, 5117.15166951954, 2554.39360278004, 19016.8868698684, 
8142.14852336025, 7131.73386600093, 4381.92237186042, 12230.6517363978, 
29687.1245110841, 22990.1972880239, 25934.9507205883, 25930.8258700104, 
17400.0724577244, 23371.4325260303, 34050.4259257071, 25091.2477340477, 
26939.4686071742, 23634.7179234314, 18412.4261018115, 19694.858763565, 
18613.1031024236, 27333.4026822017, 20189.9207118266, 22650.2972646603, 
24385.5429151823, 22263.0958498778, 12170.8501025214, 22054.2325444487, 
25510.5202235517, 4675.51312666485, 1561.73306481864, 8574.3199271613, 
1354.70278090383, 24957.1601514159, 19768.346625788, 4730.42768489829, 
19224.9150054583, 3285.72948903804, 17218.3966499476, 17814.201, 
22380.532114835, 6424.07165435052, 9712.40889037647, 21830.8738276867, 
12543.5565, 25540.573294955, 30456.6854998026, 26497.6346464698, 
32504.4187638633, 35193.0067560117, 7785.56481392295, 28545.6757735812, 
26137.1708056318, 2444.5645303282, 34296.0458183154, 19966.6912957546
), var3 = c("2", "1", "0", "7", "7", "1", "2", "2", "7", "2", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "7", "7", "2", "7", "0", 
"0", "7", "1", "7", "0", "1", "1", "7", "7", "0", "7", "0", "0", 
"1", "0", "0", "7", "1", "0", "7", "0", "0"), var4 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("B", "L", "LB", 
"U"), class = "factor"), var5 = c(43.8839807246273, 70.9849809812705, 
108.3123612557, 18.5067346403427, 9.30378992188086, 63.3011740227475, 
28.1072745643121, 28.5083339976212, 16.0029814963776, 43.4384982552552, 
95.5961125739346, 75.5159676257879, 86.6707470294212, 86.547081313194, 
58.7043591350055, 76.5451886211294, 109.786605681324, 83.2299608979667, 
88.7213157801791, 77.7420172038402, 59.2559304416528, 65.7914032345122, 
62.7598600887958, 91.7197286498123, 69.3290728743263, 76.1868976863145, 
83.0788269571258, 77.2892129514035, 41.7133254989406, 71.8765746703731, 
87.2475094008255, 16.8066086188985, 4.81454371884126, 29.0976854774272, 
6.63776939563476, 82.4170530759177, 65.430933660396, 16.9835727406131, 
61.0138926544893, 12.1712730422232, 56.4363564217849, 60.2270911399615, 
75.0308785572054, 22.0798362938508, 34.5931870329142, 72.8849996289418, 
44.307788355451, 82.7342263022031, 98.5680497957899, 88.5065672966968, 
106.805403349049, 115.732643399077, 28.3884997119228, 96.4257905149245, 
86.8582791738412, 9.42521951609614, 114.232961213524, 66.7531405760279
), var6 = c(246.386415870509, 102.627718638554, 40.5305212705092, 
196.842873553088, 164.022947554134, 75.7267072687521, 38.5276353169452, 
100.950606398559, 520.989766269837, 2.67489943916838, 600.966610777077, 
78.0325627771947, 32.7335380376157, 268.415070039536, 32.6816903646549, 
5.87551857731808, 179.326151601789, 20.4131166389686, 3.45008167868172, 
82.3102215219561, 100.56612096066, 10.1273398507419, 28.8644961441366, 
68.6775279676419, 140.999013629825, 1.7994802384114, 74.150850208548, 
434.675626693473, 77.4721303629495, 296.899295360127, 102.271469391752, 
83.7968946136107, 275.946289424453, 367.500725949366, 171.757704170549, 
177.429544428664, 40.6668074848761, 110.476576802597, 130.656699587288, 
216.176847219466, 44.7592760270898, 121.654428880646, 82.6255713213243, 
417.967735185252, 164.593370525853, 20.9860563319626, 27.2371464251141, 
108.39625696672, 238.703595397891, 44.3123444116671, 195.644038263642, 
147.354686635324, 194.618203925983, 111.410515414297, 134.090660954799, 
24.3810724829099, 20.8960565535128, 65.352646504575)), .Names = c("var1", 
"var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6"), row.names = c(NA, -58L
), class = "data.frame")
```